# Open remote Unix server files in local Emacs

Tags: ssh, emacs

I am using Emacs 24 in Ubuntu. Could you please help me on how to open remote server files?

The remote server runs CentOS. I am logging into the remote server over SSH using a private key.

I tried with following commands in Emacs 24,

`Ctrl-x` `Ctrl -f` `~/ssh username@server-IP:/home/prasad/test.sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open a file using `ssh` in Emacs by specifying `/ssh:`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> then

```
/ssh:username@server:/home/prasad/test.sh
```